Does this sentence require a second "if" or a second "are"?

I see people living their lives unaffected by these horrors and wonder if my tears are a sign of weakness or their dry eyes a sign of callousness.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?
Does it require a second "if" after the word "or"?
Does it require a second "are" after the the word "eyes"?

I'd prefer repeating are in "dry eyes are a sign." It is more poetic without the extra if, though it's harmless.

@YosefBaskin If they repeat "if" then they definitely need to repeat "are". But there's something "literate" about omitting "are" in the existing language.

You sometimes see a comma in place of an omitted word, although if you did that, you'd probably need a comma before "or" as well. But this isn't grammar, just punctuation.

@Barmar Your eyes are perennially sharp. A new idea, add a comma: "If my tears are a sign of weakness or their dry eyes, of callousness."

Questions along the lines of "Is this OK" can get more valuable answers if you explain why you think there might be a problem. Then, instead of "nope, it's fine," we can discuss the misunderstanding.

I think it is correct.
If I understand your sentence correctly, the "if" should not be repeated because the "if" here is equivalent to "whether". The "are" can be omitted as it is already used in a similar structure earlier. So, the sentence is equivalent to:
"
I see people living their lives unaffected by these horrors and wonder whether my tears are a sign of weakness or their dry eyes [are] a sign of callousness.
"

"I wonder whether my tears are a sign of weakness or their dry eyes a sign of callousness" strikes my ear as ungrammatical.    Not sure why you think changing if to whether illuminates anything about omitted [are].

@TimR I didn't think they are related. To me, changing if to whether illuminates why a second if/whether is not necessary. Whether "are" can be omitted is a separate issue. I just happen to think that it can be. Or it's not wrong to omit the "are". Personally, I think the sentence is easier to read without omitting the "are".

Preface: Your sentence is fine.
. . .
Your elided verb in their dry eyes [are] a sign of callousness displays gapping—a perfectly natural form of ellipsis.
A comma to mark the gap is only necessary when confusion or hilarity would otherwise ensue. Here’s what one style guide has to say:

6.54: Commas to indicate elision
A comma is often used to indicate the omission of a word or words
readily understood from the context. In Illinois there are
seventeen such schools; in Ohio, twenty; in Indiana,
thirteen. Thousands rushed to serve him in victory; in
defeat, none.
The comma may be omitted if the elliptical construction is clear
without it. One student excels at composition, another at
mathematics, and the third at sports. Jasper missed her
and she him.
Source: The Chicago Manual of
Style
(login required)

So, you might not need a comma in, for example:

I liked the elephant and the elephant me.

But you might want one in:

I liked the elephant and my father the clown.

(I think you have two different questions here, but to address the second one briefly . . . An independent clause can contain a dependent clause. But a dependent clause can’t contain an independent clause (warning: grammar terms vary). Your whole if-clause is a dependent clause. You can insert another if if you want, and then you will have coordinated dependent clauses. But the coordination comma for independent clauses would not apply there.)

The Wikipedia article you cite says gapping can't apply across finite clause boundaries. Do you not consider "my tears are a sign of weakness" to be a finite clause?

Very helpful explanation. Thanks

@TimR — Under Basic Examples: Some ate bread, and others [ate] rice. Do you not consider some ate bread to be a finite clause?

"Some ate bread or others rice." ?

@TimR — What is your point there? Some ate bread or others ate rice doesn't make sense either — nothing to do with gapping.

Why do you say it has nothing to do with gapping? The page you cited gives examples with or; it refers to "coordinate structures" and includes or among the "coordinators; and the sentence provided by the OP uses or.

@TimR — You can’t gap Some ate bread or others ate rice because it doesn’t make sense to begin with. You can gap whether my tears are a sign of weakness or their dry eyes [are] a sign of callousness. “Gapping usually elides minimally a finite verb and further any non-finite verbs that are present.”

@TinfoilHat My underlying point is that and and or conjuncts work differently.

I don't think the sentence is correct as it is missing a necessary word, one that cannot be elided, shown here in bold:

I see people living their lives unaffected by these horrors and wonder if my tears are a sign of weakness or their dry eyes are a sign of callousness.

Per the Wikipedia gapping link:

[gapping] cannot apply across a finite clause boundary

We can eliminate the first of the coordinated verb phrases to simplify; doing so does not affect the syntax of the clauses in question:

I ...  wonder if my tears are a sign of weakness or their dry eyes are a sign of callousness.


I wonder if
{my tears are a sign of weakness} finite clause
or
{their dry eyes are a sign of callousness}

This is not grammatical (to my inner ear when I say the words aloud):

I wonder if
the planet's sky is red
or
the planet's sea orange.

But we could do this:

I wonder if
the planet's sky might be red
or
the planet's sea orange.

or this:

I wonder if
{my tears could be | might be a sign of weakness}
or
{their dry eyes  a sign of callousness}

could be and might be are not finite forms. They do not show tense, person, or number.

Whoever downvoted, please explain why you think the Wikipedia article is wrong. Or do you not consider "my tears are a sign of weakness" a finite clause?

There's nothing wrong with Are my dry eyes a sign of weakness or their dry eyes a sign of callousness. It's very much like Wikipedia's example of Fred likes to pet the cat, and Sally  the dog. So why should putting I wonder if in front make any difference?

I am also wondering whether the Wikipedia article is wrong. I don't see anything wrong with Sam said that they spoke German, and Charlene that they spoke Spanish. When you drop the that they spoke from the last clause, it clearly becomes ungrammatical, but isn't my altered example also gapping across a clause boundary.

Those "Sam said"  subordinate clause structures are hardly the same  as I wonder if {independent finite clause} or {independent finite clause}

I think the downvote (not my downvote) shows that not all native English speakers agree by the rules that Wikipedia prescribes (my grammar sense certainly doesn't). So the question becomes: where did the Wikipedia editor find these rules, and did they come from a trustworthy source?

@PeterShor My innate sense of English grammar, my gut feeling, told me that the original formulation in OP's question, which dropped "are", was off, and when I restated that question using modal "could be" and dropped "are" it sounded  fine to me.  I visited the Wikipedia article afterwards.

@PeterShor I dont think the Wikipedia article is "prescriptive" in nature.
